# Im getting this error when i try to run the "hello world" at the kivymd getting started page

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

So, im trying to learn kivy with kivymd and i dont know why the "hello world" app doenst work

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center")


MainApp().run()
```

it returns me this error:

[AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5dsG.png)

Comment: The code you provided works without error. Try uninstalling/reinstalling kivy and kivymd

Comment: i did that several times and the result is the same. Actually, every single kivy code i tried to run gave me the same error.

Comment: are you running it in a virtual environment?